# extract header file exported Target (Shared Library) using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

##### Background

- I am trying to use the [export/import](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html) feature of `CMake`.
- My project structure as like as follows

```sh
cmake_export_import
|-- child_project
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- child.h
|   `-- src
|       |-- child.cpp
|       `-- main.cpp
`-- parent_project
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- include
    |   `-- parent.h
    `-- src
        |-- main.cpp
        `-- parent.cpp
```

- I want to use the property of `parent_project` into `child_project`

> I will not use `add_subdirectory` in `child_project` to add the `parent project` Also I will not do `make install` during building `parent_project`. This is my limitation or requirements, whatever you say.

##### Approach

###### Building parent proj

- I have followed [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets-from-the-build-tree) to achieve this.
- `CMakeLists.txt` from `parent_project`

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(parent)

# Set the main target name to the project name
set(MAIN_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})

# executable file path
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin)

# Create the C++ shared library
add_library(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parent.cpp)

# Targetting header files for the target ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib
target_include_directories(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

# Set the name of the binary file and the output directory
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "parent_executable")
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Set the name of the lib and the output directory
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PROPERTIES RELEASE_OUTPUT_NAME "parent_library")
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

target_link_libraries(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib)

target_include_directories(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PUBLIC
                           ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

install(TARGETS ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib
        EXPORT parent_Targets
)

# # exporting target from build tree
export(EXPORT parent_Targets
       FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../cmake_export/parent_Targets.cmake"
       NAMESPACE cmake_exp_imp_parent::
)
```

- I have build the `parent project`

  ```sh
  cd parent_project
  mkdir build && cd build
  cmake .. && make
  ```
- Then I can see in the root of `parent project` a folder with a generated `.cmake` file `cmake_export/parent_Targets.cmake`

###### Building child proj

- `CMakeLists.txt` from `child_project`

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(child)

# Set the main target name to the project name
set(MAIN_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})

# executable file path
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin)

# including the generated cmake of parent proj
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../../parent_project/cmake_export/parent_Targets.cmake)

# get the include header property
get_target_property(PARENT_INCLUDES cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

add_library(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/src/child.cpp)

# Targetting header files for the target ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib
target_include_directories(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                                                          ${PARENT_INCLUDES})

add_executable(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

# Set the name of the binary file and the output directory
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "child_executable")
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Set the name of the lib and the output directory
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PROPERTIES RELEASE_OUTPUT_NAME "child_library")
set_target_properties(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

target_link_libraries(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib
                                                     cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib)
```

- I have build the `child project`

  ```sh
  cd child_project
  mkdir build && cd build
  cmake .. && make
  ```
- Project is perfectly build.

### But i am not satisfied here. Maybe I am decoding the CMake documentation in a wrong way.

#### Want to know

- I have used the following lines i child project CMake file to get the `header file of the parent projet`. But truly I don't want to use this rather I am inclined to fetch automatically the path from the `exported target by importing`.

```sh
# including the generated cmake of parent proj
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../../parent_project/cmake_export/parent_Targets.cmake)

# get the include header property
get_target_property(PARENT_INCLUDES cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

And then I have appended the variable `${PARENT_INCLUDES}`

```sh
target_include_directories(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                                                          ${PARENT_INCLUDES})
```

This helped me to find the `header file` of `parent project`.

- But my query is as `parent project's target` is exported so is not is also exported it's all dependencies (I mean the header file path)?
- One snipet from the generated cmake file

```sh
set_target_properties(cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "Users/cmake_export_import/parent_project/include"
)
```

Here, i can see that the header file path of the parent project is added. But, how do I use it without using `get_target_property`? I have found [here abpout **INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) and thinking somehow it is available while I use `target_link_libraries` to link the `exported target`.

Eg:

```sh
target_link_libraries(${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_executable ${MAIN_TARGET_NAME}_lib
                                                     cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib)
```

Any idea is highly appreciable.

Comment: The error message is emitted when `child_lib` library is built. This library is NOT linked with `cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib` (you link only the target `child_executable`), that is why it cannot find `parent.h` file.

Comment: Side note: `.cmake` files from installed or exported projects are normally consumed with [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/find_package.html) command, not by `include`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , finally I have fixed the issue. Checked the generated `cmake` file and found that one of the parameters of `set_target_properties` to include header is `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. Just used in child_proj cmake file `# get the include header property
get_target_property(PARENT_INCLUDES cmake_exp_imp_parent::parent_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)`. And then `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${PARENT_INCLUDES})`. It has worked. Do you think Is there any pitfall?

Comment: @Tsyvarev -- reply_1st_comment : That one i know and that's why written how to import header of parent proj. Reply_2nd_comment : Do i need to create the package and if YES, does this process require any install/ sudo? I haven't read yet, I will surely.

Comment: @Tsyvarev may you kindly read the question again. I have updated the query. Unfortunately, I was not pointing to the focused point of my desire.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I guess no need to read my previous comment, found the solution with another question :D .

Comment: The first comment is the answer. Thanks @Tsyvarev. Though, wasted time too before seeing the comment [which is reflected in my first comment].